# How to create a new mySQL database user from php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I was wondering if there was a way to create a new user for my MySQL Database? I'm trying to add basic log-in functionality that will allow the user to connect to database. If user has no account, then I want to create a new one. This is what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
   <?php
        $username = "root";
        $password = "root";
        $hostname = "localhost"; 

        //connection to the database
        $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
          or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
        echo "Connected to MySQL<br>"; 
        $selected = mysql_select_db("contactsDB",$dbhandle) 
            or die("Could not select examples");    
        echo "Found contacts DB";
        ?>
</body>
```

Everything connects properly, but now, instead of having to type in the username and password (root), I want user to type their username and password. Again, if they don't have one, then I want to create a new one.

Comment: Are you trying to have input fields on the page for the user to enter the fields?

Comment: Yea, I have that already. The main issue I'm having is creating new database users. Basically, I'm trying to create a contacts page that will store all your contacts once you create an account(database user that stores all your contacts). I have to be able to create a new user through my PhP code; no idea how. @KingCodeFish

Answer (score 1):

You need atleast one admin account to create a user with less privilege.

Please refer to 
[create db and user mysql and set privileges php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720587/create-db-and-user-mysql-and-set-privileges-php)
which is a good reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly possible, but one thing I would stay clear of is logging in as root to do these commands.

With that in mind a method similar to this may work.

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', password);
mysql_query("CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';");
mysql_query("GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'username'@'localhost'");
mysql_close();
```

If you have a dedicated database for these new users, you can easily assign it then.