# Assign phpmyadmin's user to a database from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I was wondering if it's possible to add a phpmyadmin user to a newly created database, directly from the SQL query, without going to the admin panel.

I tried the following:

```
 mysqli_query($mysqli, "CREATE DATABASE test_db");
 mysqli_query($mysqli, "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test_db.* TO 'DBUser'@'%'");
```

Of course 'DBUser' already exists, but I can't get it to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Of course, PHPmyAdmin is nothing more than just a fancy GUI.

Comment: Yea, that I know, but how to make it work?

Comment: take a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720587/create-db-and-user-mysql-and-set-privileges-php)

Comment: @MohamedSa'ed I already did check that, but couldn't find my answer. I tried with that code there, but it doesn't work. Unless I'm missing something.